# Java concurrency - how to properly lock and realease thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to understand how do i properly use wait and notify without Semafor or CountdownLatch. lets have a simple example

```
Response call(long[] l)
{
   final Response r = new Response();
   Thread t = Thread.currentThread(); //get current thread
   thread2(l,s -> {
       response.setObject(s);
       t.notify(); //wake up first thread 
   });
   Thread.currentThread().wait(); //wait until method thread2 finishes
   return response;
} 
void thread2(long[] l, Consumer c)
{
    //start new thread and call
    c.accept(resultobject);
}
```

Is my behavior acceptable? is it required to put .notify method in a synchronized block?

Comment: Nope. Don't ever use notify and wait with Thread objects.

Comment: Also, both `wait` and `notify` require that the calling thread own the monitor on that target object.

Comment: See the Java tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html  The wait()/notify() mechanism is a primitive facility that is supposed to be used in a very specific way to implement higher-level synchronization objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is required to put `notify` into a `synchronized block`. The main logic is the following:

**Pseudo code of the threads waiting for a given state of an Object:**

```
synchronized(mutex) {
    while (object state is not the expected one) {
        mutex.wait();
    }
    // Code here that manipulates the Object that now has the expected state
}
```

**Pseudo code of the threads that modify the state of the Object and want to notify other threads:**

```
synchronized(mutex) {
    // Code here that modifies the state of the object which could release
    // the threads waiting for a given state
    mutex.notifyAll();
}
```